# Triangle issue in Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hy can someone please give me a little hand here. I want to make this triangle.

[image]

How to find middle point in triangle? However can someone point me, this is what I have so far.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (0,1);
  \coordinate (C) at (1.7,0);
  \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (A);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'd really appreciate if some could help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TikZ has powerful libraries which you can use. The `angles,quotes` are helpful for drawing the angles with anotations, and the `intersections` can be used to find the middle point `X` in the triangle. Also note how to find the point `(a)` using the perpendicular coordinates `\coordinate (a) at ($(C)!(A)!(B)$);`, which means the projection of `A` onto `CB`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,angles,quotes,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (0,1);
  \coordinate (C) at (1.7,0);
  \coordinate (a) at ($(C)!(A)!(B)$);
  \coordinate (w) at ($(A)!0.3!(C)$);
  \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (A) -- (a);
  \draw[shorten >=-7pt] (B)--(w) node[below right]{w};
  \coordinate (X) at (intersection of A--a and B--w);
  \draw pic["$\cdot$", draw, angle radius=2mm] {angle=B--a--A}
        pic["$\cdot$", draw, angle radius=2mm] {angle=C--A--B}
        pic["$\varepsilon$", draw, angle radius=3mm] {angle=w--X--a};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]